# Sorting in AdvancedDatagrid in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I am using AdvancedDatagrid in Flex 3. One column of AdvancedDatagrid contains numbers and alphabets. When I sort this column, numbers come before alphabets (Default behavior of internal sorting of AdvancedDatagrid). But I want alphabets to come before number when I sort.

I know I will have to write the custom sort function. But can anybody give some idea on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sortCompareFunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction)

> The AdvancedDataGrid control uses this function to sort the elements of the data provider collection. The function signature of the callback function takes two parameters and has the following form:
>
> `mySortCompareFunction(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int`
>
> obj1 — A data element to compare.
>
> obj2 — Another data element to compare with obj1.
>
> The function should return a value based on the comparison of the objects:
>
> - -1 if obj1 should appear before obj2 in ascending order.
> - 0 if obj1 = obj2.
> - 1 if obj1 should appear after obj2 in ascending order.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="mySort" 
    dataField="colData"/>
```

Try the following sort compare function.

```
public function mySort(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int
{
    var s1:String = obj1.colData;
    var s2:String = obj2.colData;
    var result:Number = s1.localeCompare(s2);
    if(result != 0)
        result = result > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    if(s1.match(/^\d/))
    {
        if(s2.match(/^\d/))
            return result;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    else if(s2.match(/^\d/))
        return -1;
    else 
        return result;
}
```

It checks the first character of strings and pushes the ones that start with a digit downwards in the sort order. It uses [localeCompare](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html#localeCompare%28%29) to compare two strings if they both start with letters or digits - otherwise it says the one starting with a letter should come before the one with digit. Thus `abc` will precede `123` but `a12` will still come before `abc`.

If you want a totally different sort where letters always precede numbers irrespective of their position in the string, you would have to write one from the scratch - [String::charCodeAt](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html#charCodeAt%28%29) might be a good place to start.